# Short circuit and operator precedence in C

Tags: c, operators, logical-operators, operator-precedence, short-circuiting

I know that logical operators in C follow short circuiting but my doubt is that are short circuiting and operator precedence rules not opposing each other. See the below example :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    int b=5;

    a=0 && --b;
    printf("%d %d",a,b);

    return 0;
}
```

According to the precedence rules, the highest precedence is of the prefix operator. So `--b` should be evaluated first and then the `&&` and at last result will be assigned to `a`. So expected output should be `0 4`. But in this case the second operand of `&&` never actually executes and result comes out to be `0 5`.

Why precedence rules are not being applied here. Are logical operators exempted from precedence rules? If yes, what other operators show such behavior? And what is the logic behind this behavior?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're conflating two related but different topics: *operator precedence* and *order of evaluation*.

The operator precedence rules dictate how various operators are grouped together.  In the case of this expression:

```
 a=0 && --b;
```

The operators are grouped like this:

```
 a = (0 && (--b));
```

This has no effect however on which order the operands are evaluated in.  The `&&` operator in particular dictates that the left operand is evaluated first, and if it evaluates to 0 the right operand is not evaluated.

So in this case the left side of `&&` which is `0` is evaluated, and because it is 0 the right side which is `--b` is not evaluated, so `b` is not incremented.

Here's another example of the difference between operator precedence and order of evaluation.

```
int val()
{
    static x = 2;
    x *= 2;
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    int result = val() + (5 * val());
    printf("%d\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

What will the above program print?  As it turns out, there are two possibilities, and both are valid.

In this expression:

```
val() + (5 * val())
```

There are no operators that have any type of short circuit behavior.  So the compiler is free to evaluate the individual operands of both `+` and `*` in any order.

If the first instance of `val()` is evaluated first, the result will be `4 + ( 5 * 8) == 44`.  If the second instance of `val()` is evaluated first, the result will be `8 + (5 * 4) == 28`.  Again, both are valid since the operands may be evaluated in any order.

Comment: Apart from logical operators are there any other operators that follow short circuiting ? and you said that there is no specific order for `+` and `*` but this table : https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence  shows the order to be left to right, Why so ??

Comment: @Noshiii Those rules only dictate how operands are grouped, not when they are evaluated.  Besides `||` and `&&`, the evaluation of parameters of a function call are sequenced before the actual call, although the parameters may be evaluated in any order.

Comment: ok got it but a silly question. So how will we know the order of evaluation of various operators. I mean is there some sort of table or something, where i can see.

Comment: @Noshiii The [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) describes how the individual operators work.  But in most cases the order of evaluation of operands is **unspecified** as my example shows.  To make a simpler example of the above, `val() - val()` could be `4` or `-4`.

Comment: So for unspecified operators, evaluation order is compiler dependent. Right ??

Comment: @Noshiii Not only compiler dependent, but the order could change with a minor code change or recompiling with different options.

Comment: @Noshiii: That cppreference page talks about operator *associativity*, which controls how expressions like `a + b + c` are parsed.  "Left-to-right" associativity means that those operators and operands are grouped as `(a + b) + c`.  However, each of `a`, `b`, and `c` may be evaluated *in any order*.  `a + b` may be evaluated before *or* after `c`.

Comment: @John Bode if i consider an expression like `a/b*c`  . How will you justify its order of evaluation ??

Comment: @Noshiii The operator precedence rules say it parses as `(a/b)*c` because `*` and `/` are at the same precedence level and are grouped left to right.  The order of evaluations rules say that 1) `a`, `b`, and `c` may be evaluated in any order, 2) `a` and `b` must be evaluated before `a / b`, and 3) `a / b` and `c` must be evaluated before `a / b * c`.

Comment: @dbush If i explicitly write `(a/b)*c` , won't that force `a/b` to be evaluated first ? I read it at many places that parantheses are used to force some expression to be evaluated first.

Comment: @Noshiii Parenthesis only enforce grouping.  `c` could be evaluated before `a / b`.

Comment: @Noshiii: Again, in arithmetic expressions, grouping and precedence do not control the order in which subexpressions are evaluated.  With `(a/b)*c`, each of `a`, `b`, and `c` may be evaluated *in any order*.  On a parallel system they may be evaluated simultaneously.  All that matters is that the *result* of `a/b` is multiplied by the *result* of `c`, but the exact order in which those results are obtained is not specified or fixed.  It doesn't even have to be consistent within the same program.

Comment: Got it finally. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

**Precedence** affects how ambiguous expressions are parsed. When there are multiple ways to interpret an expression with several operators, precedence tells us which interpretation is correct. Think of precedence as a mechanism to figure out where the implied parentheses are.

For example in the statement in question there are two valid ways to parse it. If `=` had higher precedence than `&&` it could be read as:

```
(a = 0) && --b;
```

But since `&&` has higher precedence, it's actually interpreted as:

```
a = (0 && --b);
```

(Note: Your code's formatting suggests it's the first. Be careful not to mislead!)

**Evaluation order** is different from precedence. They're related, but independent concepts. After precedence is used to determine the correct parsing of an expression, evaluation order tells us the order to evaluate the operands in. Is it left to right? Right to left? Simultaneous? Unspecified?

For the most part evaluation order is left unspecified. Operators like `+` and `*` and `<<` have no defined evaluation order. The compiler is allowed to do whatever it likes, and the programmer must not write code that depends on any particular order. `a + b` could evaluate `a` then `b`, or `b` then `a`, or it could even interweave their evaluations.

`=` and `&&`, among others, are exceptions. `=` is always evaluated right to left, and `&&` is left to right with short circuiting.

Here's how evaluation proceeds step-by-step for our statement:

1. `a = (0 && --b)`, `=` evaluated right to left

   1. `0 && --b`, `&&` evaluated left to right with short circuiting

      1. `0`, evaluates false which triggers short circuiting and cancels the next step
      2. `--b`, not evaluated due to short circuiting
      3. result is `0`
   2. `a`, variable reference evaluated
   3. `a = 0`, assignment occurs and overall result is `0`

> You said that there is no specific order for `+` and `*`, but [this table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) shows the order to be left to right. Why so?

The last column of that table is **associativity**. Associativity breaks precedence ties when we use the same operator twice, or when we use operators with the same precedence.

For example, how should we read `a / b / c`. Is it:

- `(a / b) / c`, or
- `a / (b / c)`?

According to the table `/` has left-to-right associativity, so it's the first.

What about chained assignments like `foo = bar = baz`? Now, assignment has right-to-left associativity, so the correct parsing is `foo = (bar = baz)`.

If this all gets confusing, focus on one simple rule of thumb:

**"Precedence and associativity are independent from order of evaluation."**

Comment: "*For the most part evaluation order is left unspecified. Operators like `+` and `*` and `<<` have no defined evaluation order. The compiler is allowed to do whatever it likes, and the programmer must not write code that depends on any particular order. `a + b` could evaluate `a` then `b`, or `b` then `a`, or it could even interweave their evaluations.*" - So, to be safe and to ensure the compiler evaluates an expression in the way one want, parenthesis is the magic remedy? Like f.e. `(a) + (b)`. Or are their any situations where even parenthesis won´t affect the compiler-specific evaluation?

Comment: Parentheses do not influence evaluation order. Adding them won't help. Put them in separate statements, or use an operator that does like `,` (the comma operator), `&&`, or `||`.

Comment: Apart from logical operators are there any other operators that follow short circuiting ? and you said that there is no specific order for `+` and `*` but this table : https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence shows the order to be left to right, Why so ??

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. Your last line cleared all my doubts .

Answer (score 0):

`operator &&` 's order of evaluation is left to right.

`=` has lower precedence, in fact only  `ooperator ,` has lower precedence than `=`.

So the expresssion will read `a = (0 && --b)` being 0 evaluated first given the mentioned order of evaluation.

Since `0` evaluates to `false`, there is no need to evaluate the second part of the expression because `false && true` is `false`, given the first part of the expression is `false`, the expression will always be `false`.

If you had `||` operator the second part of the expression would have to be evaluated.

Comment: Ya i got it but still it has 3 different operators. If there was no logical operator in this, we would have used the precedence table to solve this question. But we are not doing so now ?

Comment: @Noshiii, there was some confusion in my answer, I corrected it, I hope I didn't confused you further.

Comment: `=` operator does not have "right to left order of evaluation". Like all operators in C except for `&&`, `||`, `,`, and `?:`, it evaluates its operands in any order, possibly simultaneously.

Comment: @Cubbi, correct, my mistake, interestingly I [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62051230/6865932) yesterday related to this.

Answer (score 0):

Operator precedence doesn't necessarily tell that an expression gets executed first, it just means that the expression is parsed such that the result of the higher-precedence operation is used in the lower-precedence operation and not the other way around. The actual expressions only get evaluated if they need to!

Answer (score -2):

Operator precedence is not all that plays in the game.  There is also order of evaluation.  And that mandates that a=0 is evaluated first (evaluation order is from left to right), and then right part after the && is not evaluated at all.

That is how C works.