# Contradiction about Order of Evaluation of operands

Tags: c, recursion, operator-precedence, operands, c-standard-library

When I study recursive functions in C from deitel c, I read this sentence:

> *Standard C does not specify the order in which the operands of most operators (including +) are to be evaluated.*

But also the book says that:

> *associativity of '+' from left to right*

Order of evaluation of operands:

[image: order of evaluation of operands]

Could anyone explain why this is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Order of evaluation and associativity are two different things, take the example:

```
int x = func1() - func2() - func3(); //having int return types
```

In this expression you can't know if `func1()` will be evaluated first or last, meaning, you don't know which function will be called and return its value first, however you know that the associativity, as with `+`, will be left-to-right, first `func1() - func2()` then the result of that subtraction `- func3()`.

> *There is no concept of left-to-right or right-to-left evaluation in C, which is not to be confused with left-to-right and right-to-left associativity of operators: the expression `f1() + f2() + f3()` is parsed as `(f1() + f2()) + f3()` due to left-to-right associativity of `operator+`, but the function call to `f3()` may be evaluated first, last, or between `f1()` or `f2()` at run time.*

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order