# I’m learning to code in C and cant understand the short circuit behaviour of the logical expressions. Do they not follow the precedence order

Tags: c, logical-operators, operator-precedence, short-circuit-evaluation

I’m learning to code in C. I was going through the logical expressions but then this question came and I couldn’t understand ? Like are logical operators exceptional in case of precedence. Let’s take this one example:

```
i = 1; j = 1; k = 1;
printf("%d ", ++i || ++j && ++k);
printf("%d %d %d", i, j, k);
```

The compiler answer is 1 ,2,1,1 which means it short circuited. But i can’t understand that why didn’t the compiler follow the precedence (++ has higher precedence than ||) or is it just the way it’s designed in case of logical expressions?  I just want to confirm. Thanks.[it shows operator precedence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXZJs.jpg)

Comment: I think you're confusing operator precedence and *order of evaluation*. See [Short circuit and operator precedence in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61750969/short-circuit-and-operator-precedence-in-c)

Comment: The precedence doesn't strictly define the evaluation order. E.g. in `a + b == c * d`, the `==` must be evaluated after `+` and `*` because of the precedence, but `*` doesn't have to be evaluated before `+`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of sequence points, which are markers for which prior side-effects (such as assignment/increment) must be complete by, and two of those sequence points are `&&` and `||`. The ternary `control?true:false` operator also has sequence points in it, hence why the side-effects of the first operand are complete before the second or third operands are evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

The short circuit behaviour of `||` in C is only evaluating the right hand side if the left side was evaluated false.

In your case:

```
    int i=1, j=1, k=1;
    printf("%d ", ++i || ++j && ++k);  // prints 1 and only increments i
    printf("%d %d %d", i, j, k);
```

As the right hand side is never evaluated the variables `j` and `k` are not incremented.

Answer (score 0):

You must distinguish precedence that determines the way expressions are parsed and evaluation rules which determine what parts of expressions are evaluated and, in some cases, in which order:

- `++` indeed has higher precedence than `||` and so does `&&` so the expression `printf("%d ", ++i || ++j && ++k);` is parsed as:

  ```
   printf("%d ", ((++i) || ((++j) && (++k))));
  ```
- evaluation rules determine what parts of the expression get evaluated: to evaluate `A || B`, `A` is evaluated first and the result is tested for its truth value: if `A` is true, ie: if it is not false, then the expression value is `1` and `B` is not evaluated at all (this is called *short cut evaluation*). If `A` evaluates to a false value, then `B` is evaluated and the value of the whole expression is `0` if `B` evaluates to a false value and `1` otherwise.

  The same rule applies to `A && B` except `B` is evaluated if and only if `A` evaluates to a truth value.

As a consequence, the steps to evaluate `printf("%d ", ++i || ++j && ++k);` are:

- `++i` evaluates to the value of `i + 1`, and `i` is incremented as a side effect before the next sequence point. The value is `2`.
- `||` causes a sequence point, and since the left operand is non `0`, its right operand `++j && ++k` is not evaluated at all, so no side effects on `j` or `k` will happen. The value of the expression is `1` and `i` gets the value `2`.
- the argument value `1` is passed to `printf`
- the argument value `"%d "` is passed to `printf`. Note that the order of evaluation of function arguments and function objects is unspecified.
- `printf` is called, outputs `1` and returns `2`, the number of bytes produced, which is ignored.
- the next `printf` outputs `2 1 1` because `i` was incremented and neither `j` nor `k` were.